# how to use params.require in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a private method like this for a registration form which has four fields, `firstname`, `email`, `password` and `confirm password`. I am not sure how to check for `password confirmation`.

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
               :password_confirmation)
end
```

Previously, i was using the below code.How do i convert the code below to use params.require

```
User.new(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], 
     password: params[:password], confirmpassword: params[:password])
```

Comment: Is your field name is `confirmpassword`? Then if you want to `whitelist` it,you have do it like this `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
               :confirmpassword)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your code

```
User.new(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], 
     password: params[:password], confirmpassword: params[:password])
```

I suspect that you're not using `password_confirmation` field. In that case, this is how you will use `params.require`

```
def user_params
    params.require(:name)
    params.require(:email)
    params.require(:password)
    params.permit(:name,:email,:password)
end
```

**UPDATED AS PER COMMENT**

if you are using `password_confirmation` field, then this should be like in **RAILS 3.x.x**

```
User.new(name: params[:name], email: params[:email], 
     password: params[:password], confirmpassword: params[:password_confirmation])
```

And, this is how it will be with `strong_parameters` (usually with **rails 4.x.x**)

```
User.new(user_params)

def user_params
    params.require(:name)
    params.require(:email)
    params.require(:password)
    params.require(:confirm_password)
    params.permit(:name,:email,:password,:confirm_password)
end
```

Comment: I have a password confirmation field?

Comment: in that case, you can whitelist `password_confirmation` field just like `password`

Comment: Perfect, <%= password_field_tag :confirm_password, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "confirm password" %> so in my case it would be :confirm_password right? as my name field is confirm_password

Comment: @theJava You should make it clear that your field name is `confirm_password`.Currently you have said `confirm password`.