# render :new with URL parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am newer to ruby on rails and I am trying to fix an application that I inherited from an previous employee.

Basically a user clicks on a link from an email that looks like this.
https://www.example.com/events/event_name/event_registrants/new?partner=microsoft

They leave some of the form blank and click the submit button.  The event_registration model fails because of the blank fields and then they are redirected back to https://www.example.com/events/event_name/event_registrants/new

Losing the ?partner=microsoft url parameter in the process.

I found the area of the controller that redirects them back to the site with the validation errors.  The current code does this:

```
render :new
```

I added the the if/else statement and it displays the correct page if there is not a partner...but I get an error when there is a partner.

```
if @event_registration.partner.nil?
   render :new
else
   redirect_to :action => "new", :partner => @event_registration.partner.try(:token)
end
```

This works, but I am trying to pass the @event_registration model to the redirection, so that the model validation error message can be displayed.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
jlimited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use params.require in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243051/how-to-use-params-require-in-rails-4)

Comment: This code is currently working...I just want to pass the reset of the @event_registrant through to the redirect.    redirect_to :action => "new", :partner => @event_registrant.partner.try(:token)

Answer (score 0):

Grab the params before redirect, and pass them with the redirect.

In this case:

`params = [:partner => 'microsoft']`

`redirect_to new_event_registration_path(params)`

Similar question:
[Passing parameters in rails redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to)

Comment: Do you mean `params = {:partner => 'microsoft'}` or `params = {partner: 'microsoft'}`?

Comment: The idea is that you need to pass the params with the redirect. @muistooshort yes thanks updated the syntax!